# checkbox selection, onchange go to function. [checkboxes are images. and not the actual checkbox]

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="dtree_activity">
    <ul><li><a href="#" class=""><ins class="jstree-checkbox">&nbsp;</ins>
    <ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>Fresh</a></li></ul>
</div>
```

My code:-

```
j('#dtree_activity').click(function(){
if(j('#dtree_activity li').is('.jstree-checked'))
{
    doSometin();

}
else
{
    doSometinElse();

}

});
```

What it does:-

It checks if the checkbox[Image] is clicked.. Determined by the presence of class "jstree-checked"

Problem:-

It works but the state is updates one click late.

Eg: i check the checkbox, it should doSomtin() ... but it wont
if i click again anywhere in the div it will go to doSometin()

Answer (score 1):

You've just got the logic the wrong way round.  This should help...

```
j('#dtree_activity').click(function(){
    if (j(this).find('li').is('.jstree-checked'))
    {
        //  It's already checked so we're unchecking here
        j(this).find('li').removeClass('.jstree-checked');
        doSometinElse();
    }
    else
    {
        //  It's not checked so we're checking here
        j(this).find('li').addClass('.jstree-checked');
        doSometin();
    }
});
```

Comment: no sorry mate, its the same problem. But i dont want to remove any class. Just check if it exists..

Comment: Okay - my misunderstanding then.

Comment: had to attach intreval to check for Presence of Class.

Answer (score 1):

> But i dont want to remove any class. Just check if it exists..

In this case use `hasClass()` which returns a boolean to see if the selected element has the specified class on it. For example:

```
if (j('#dtree_activity li').hasClass('jstree-checked')) {
    doSometin();
}
else {
    doSometinElse();
}
```

Further reading on [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function() {
      if(j('#dtree_activity').find('li').is('.jstree-checked'))
      {
      showGetProductBtn();
      }
      else
      { hideGetProductBtn();}
    }, 2000);
```